# Intersection of hyperspheres

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Suppose we have $n$ hyperspheres in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $m\geq n$, of centers $x_1,\ldots x_n$, $x_i\neq x_j\,\forall i,j$, and radii $r_1,\ldots ,r_n$. Suppose that, for every $i,j$, the quantities $r_i$, $r_j$ and $|x_i-x_j|$ are the side lengths of a triangle.

**Is it true that the intersection of the $n$ hyperspheres is a $m-n$-dimensional submanifold, with affine dimension greater than $m-n$?**

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: the dimension could also be higher, for example if two spheres are equal.

Comment: Oh sorry, the points are supposed to be distinct. I edited my post.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Is the question ill-posed or trivial?

Comment: Many m dimensional hyper spheres  contain the same lower dimensional hyper sphere. You need to know more about the placement (e.g. no three centers are collinear) before you can draw conclusions or tight bounds about the dimension of the intersection.  Gerhard "Upvotes Require Some More Thought" Paseman, 2018.11.20.

Comment: I get your point, actually I need to impose more conditions. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to look through the several papers on *ball polyhedra*, 
"bodies obtained as intersections of finitely many balls of the same radius,
(co-)authored by Karoly Bezdek. These papers are mostly focused on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Bezdek, Karoly, Zsolt Langi, Marton Naszodi, and Peter Papez. "Ball-polyhedra." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 38, no. 2 (2007): 201-230.
>   [Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669804001647#fig1).
>
> ---
>
> [image: Fig[1]]

---

> Bezdek, Károly, and Márton Naszódi. "Rigidity of ball-polyhedra in Euclidean 3-space." *European Journal of Combinatorics* 27, no. 2 (2006): 255-268.
>
> Kupitz, Yaakov S., Horst Martini, and Micha A. Perles. "Ball polytopes and the Vázsonyi problem." *Acta Mathematica Hungarica* 126, no. 1-2 (2010): 99-163.